# xcode 8 not running

Tags: xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode8

I installed the Xcode 8. But it stuck at licence agreement screen. I clicked agree and enter system password but Xcode stuck at same screen. Have anyone faced the same issue and their resolution.

OS Version 10.11.6 (El Captain)

[image]

Comment: If it happens every time when Xcode launches after being killed, if I were you, I would reinstall Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I think I have faced a similar issue for an older version of Xcode. What you should do is to delete the app completely and try to reinstall it. If that does not work for you, try upgrading to the latest version of MacOS and try again. I believe this is a bug on Apple's end, but it shouldn't occur again if you try these things.

Also, make sure you are connected to the internet. If you are not, it may not be able to understand that you have accepted their agreement.